# align text to base of the content box in buttons and input

Tags: html, css, button

I have this button

```
<input type="button" class="<?php echo $button_class ?> prev" name="checkout_prev_step" value="<?php echo $labels['prev'] ?>" data-action="prev"></input>
```

css:

```
#form_actions .button.yith-wcms-button.prev {
    background-image: url('assets/arrow-left.png');
    background-size: 5px;
    background-position: center left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue LT Std Bold Condensed', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    height: 45px;
}
```

As you can see on the attached image, the text inside the input "PREVIOUS" is not aligned to the bottom of the **blue** box (content box).

How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have a bottom padding, use `padding-bottom:0;` and check.

Comment: I want the bottom padding, what I don't want is the text to be higher than the bottom of the blue box (see picture).

Comment: looks like it's my font that is doing this.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a custom font, try `line-height` or use `<button>`  tag and put your text and then use `line-height`,

Comment: The font is "Helvetica Neue LT Std Condensed". It's a standard font.

Answer (score 0):

try adding those css lines to the button:

```
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
```

see if it works

Answer (score 0):

There are few options here,

1. Use `line-height` to move text little bit down.
2. Use `button` tag make it a flex box.

Example below.

[image]

[image]

I have also added a custom font to make input looks like your example
[image]

```css
.my-button
{
    background-image: url('assets/arrow-left.png');
    background-size: 5px;
    background-position: center left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue LT Std Bold Condensed', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    height: 45px;
}

.my-button-1 {
  line-height:70px
}
.my-button-2 {
   display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.my-button-3 {
   display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.my-button-9
{
    background-image: url('assets/arrow-left.png');
    background-size: 5px;
    background-position: center left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
    line-height:32px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    height: 45px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<input type="button" class="my-button" name="checkout_prev_step" value="Some text" data-action="prev"></input>


<input type="button" class="my-button my-button-1" name="checkout_prev_step" value="Some text" data-action="prev"></input>

<button class="my-button my-button-2">
   <span>Some new text</span>
</button>
<button class="my-button my-button-3">
   <span>Some new text</span>
</button>

<input type="button" class="my-button-9" name="checkout_prev_step" value="PREVIOUS" data-action="prev"></input>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't change the markup, so it's not an option to change the inputs into buttons.

Comment: The first 2 examples are CSS based without changing the html, did that work for you?